# Apple tree with brown leaves and black bark

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, apples

I have an apple tree which is at least fifteen years old and produces fruit most years. This year it has developed brown leaves on the lower branches and brown/black places on the bark near the ground. The fruit appears to be developing normally.

[image: leaves with brown spots]

[image: Stock with black bark]

I'm in Ontario Canada, which does not allow chemical pesticides, but I spray it with sulphur and insecticidal soap at least a few times in Spring.

What is likely to be the problem and what can I do about it?

Comment: In your first picture I see a fruit with a dark area. What colour is it, brown or black?

Comment: It's brown. Hadn't noticed it before.

Answer (score 1):

These symptoms match the ones of Venturia inequalis. Use a systemic fungicide against it.

Comment: Any suggestions for what to do in a place where chemical fungicides are banned?

Comment: I have read that potassium bicarbonate is used in organic farming to prevent infection, but I don't know if it is effective as a cure.